# python: using nested lists as arguments

Tags: python, list, nested, arguments

Trying to use the elements of nested lists for the arguments of a function

```
list = [[ "stringA" , 11, 22], [ "stringB", 33 , 44]]

def func ( 'str' , a , b ):
```

I know how to 
call a single element: list[0][1] and func(*list) to use the lists as an argument.

How do I use the individual elements?

Comment: Best not to shadow the builtin `list` with your own variable. I've used `lst` instead in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
func(*lst[0])
```

Often you might loop over the list

```
for item in lst:
    func(*item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to unzip the values of list. Try this.

```
list1 = [[ "stringA" , 11, 22], [ "stringB", 33 , 44]]

def func(string, a, b):
    print string, a, b

for i in list1:
    func(*i)
```

Output:

```
stringA 11 22
stringB 33 44
```